# Onchange access codeigniter function

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying using `jquery onchange`. Please take a look:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reservation").change(function() {
        var date = $("#reservation").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url();?>home',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {date_search : date},
            success: function() {
                 location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

here is my controller:

```
else if(isset($date_search)){
      $data['var'] = "Range Date";
      $explode = explode('-',$date_search);
      $start_date = inggris_date($explode[0]);
      $end_date = inggris_date($explode[1]);
      $data['tgl'] = $this->modelmodel->showdata("select MONTH(tanggal) Tanggal from transaksi where (tanggal between '$start_date' and '$end_date')and outlet = '".$this->session->userdata('username')."' group by MONTH(tanggal)");
      $data['angka'] = $this->modelmodel->showdata("select TOP 12 (cash + cc + dc + flash + piutang + reject + disc50) total from transaksi where (tanggal between '$start_date' and '$end_date')and outlet = '".$this->session->userdata('username')."'");

}
$view = 'dummy';
$this->go_to($view,$data);
```

There is no problem with my query. I'm able to get the result. My question is, how do i refresh my page with the result because when i'm use `location.reload` the result back to `default`.

My function above is a part of my controller. Here is the fullscript of my function http://pastebin.com/i5UeypGG

Comment: Are you using bootstrap??

Comment: if you reload the page than your data which comes through ajax will not visible. than why you need to reload the page.

Comment: All you need to do is to update the html element through ajax success for which the view content has to be applied. Once the controller returns a view apply the result data using **JQuery's html()** method

Comment: You would need to explain why you are using an ajax function and then trying to reload the page (instead as @VijayWilson mentions, update the view). You would also need to handle any errors in a similar fashion. If that doesn't work for you for whatever reason, just do a standard POST instead of ajax.

Comment: @Idg well. I just trying to send post, so i use ajax thats the only way i now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From now on. I change my Jquery. I'm using https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reservation").change(function() {
        var date = $("#reservation").val();
        $.redirect('<?=base_url();?>home', {date_search : date});
        });
});
</script>
```

And it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

Create another function in your controller place the current logic of the above function in it, in the function for the ajax return a path to the new link,
with the help of window.location when the ajax is complete you redirect to the new controller function.

From what i can tell your function is only displaying data so it may be easier to just use a simple link to a new controller function